# Using polyfill for formData and IE still throwing error: Object doesn't support this action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer, form-data

I am using a npm package called formdata-pollyfill which is suppose to fix the issue when using IE and `FormData` method set. Yet when I call `.set` it throws the `Object doesn't support this action` error.

```
import formData from 'formdata-polyfill'

let data = new formData(form);
data.set('foo', 'bar') // --> Object doesn't support this action
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The docs state](https://github.com/jimmywarting/FormData#updating-from-2x-to-3x) that from version 3.x you shouldn't use an imported formData since the package isn't exporting anything anymore.

So I think that you should change it to:

```
require('formdata-polyfill')

let data = new FormData(form);
data.set('foo', 'bar')
```

The change from version 2.x makes sense since this is the way most pollyfills work in my experience.